# How can I install a program from a PPA that is listed as being for 12.04 when I'm using 11.10?

Tags: ppa

I would like to install a program from a PPA that has both Oneiric and Precise versions of the same program. The Precise version of the program is 2.2 whereas the Oneiric version is 2.0

If I try an install the normal way through the software centre or the terminal, the Oneiric 2.0 version will be installed. Is there an easy way to force Ubuntu to install the Precise version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit the file inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` listing the ppa and change the distribution name from oneiric to precise.  Of course you may run into dependency problems when you try to install as the precise version may depend on libraries from precise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I don't have a /etc/sources.d folder. Is the /etc/apt/sources.list.d folder the same?

Comment: Oops, that's what I meant.  Fixed

Answer (score 6):

After having used the kindly provided answer by psusi, I also discovered an alternative GUI-based method for doing this which I'll add as some people may find it easier.

Open the Ubuntu Software centre and select **Edit > Software Sources**

Click on the PPA contains the program you wish to install and select **Edit**

[image: Dialogue box image]

Then replace the text '**Oneiric**' in the distribution field of the next menu with '**Precise**'

[image: Dialogue box image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of altering your sources list which may result in unwanted dependency problems I suggest using the program [prevu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Prevu), which is designed to backport software packages.