# How to install samsung-backlight on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, samsung

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I'd like to install samsung-backlight from Voria Tools as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38845/samsung-netbook-n150plus-screen-brightness-not-working), but after adding the PPA I can read some 404 errors for `http://ppa.launchpad.net/voria/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources` when doing `sudo apt-get update`.

Does this mean that there is no samsung-backlight for Ubuntu 12.10? How can I install it?

Comment: there some useful links here for this question:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/96601/how-can-i-install-a-program-from-a-ppa-that-is-listed-as-being-for-12-04-when-i